# VLC 3.0.6 restart on .mov file but is able to convert them to .mp4

Tags: vlc-media-player, quicktime

When I try to watch a .mov file VLC (3.0.6) keeps restarting (I need to kill the app using Task Manager).

The same VLC manages to convert this file into .mp4 and then play this correctly .mp4

Update: They work on the same VLC (3.0.6) on the Mac OS.
I couldn't play them on others player on both Mac OS nor Windows 10.

Answer (score 1):

You have probably found a bug in VLC, best reported on the
[VLC forums](https://forum.videolan.org/).
I would first perhaps re-install VLC to ensure that no corruption has occurred.

As watching and converting are not identical operations, it seems like the bug
has no effect when converting, only when watching.

As you have found a workaround for this bug, you are not blocked from watching
the video. If this happens on other videos, the problem might be deeper than
a simple bug while playing.

Comment: It happens on all videos from this source (multiple files, 4 different recording devices (but probably converted), 20h of video in total)

Comment: Are all these videos of the same type? Are they available for download? Have you tried another video player?

Comment: I guess they are the same. They are raw files from the recording company from 4 cameras. They work on the VLC on MacOS. They don't work on other players on both MacOS and Windows 10.
I started a thread on the VLC forum: https://forum.videolan.org/viewtopic.php?f=14&t=148774

Comment: VLC may have trouble with some `.mov` files. There is one workaround [mentioned here](https://www.techwalla.com/articles/vlc-will-not-play-mov-files) which you could try, to play it first for a few minutes on the QuickTime player.

Comment: The thing is it doesn't work in the QuickTime either

Comment: This is one strange video file format. You are lucky to be able to convert it.